# How to test webservice trough workbench

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, workbench, debug

I have a webservice and want to test this in workbech but get the error:

> [ {   "errorCode" : "NOT_FOUND",   "message" : "The requested resource
>   does not exist" } ]

webservice

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/SalesProduct/*')
global with sharing class WebserviceSalesproducts {
        @HttpGet
        webservice static List<Sales_Product__c> getSalesproductsByProductCode() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;

        List<Sales_Product__c> result= new List<Sales_Product__c>();

        String ProductCode = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        system.debug('ProductCode '+ ProductCode);
        try{

            Sales_Product__c  SprResult =  [SELECT id,name, Productcode__c 
                                            FROM Sales_Product__c 
                                            WHERE Productcode__c  = :ProductCode ];
            result.add(SprResult);
        }catch(exception e){
            system.debug('Error'+ e);
        }
        system.debug(result);
        if(result.size()==0){
            response.statusCode = 204;
            response.responseBody = blob.valueOf('Sorry no match');
        }

        if(result.size()>0){
            return result;
        }Else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Workbench rest explorer url:

```
/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/SalesProduct/test-product
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to try this: `/services/apexrest/SalesProduct/test-product`.

Use the `GET` verb operation from Workbench.

Comment: Thanks thas was helpful.